# Why does this reject an enum?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does this code fail?

```
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
  int a[10];
  enum { a_size = sizeof a / sizeof *a };
  std::fill(a, a + a_size, a_size);
}
```

G++ 4.1.2 and 4.4.3:

> In function 'int main()':
>   Line 5: error: no matching function for call to 'fill(int [10], int*, main()::<anonymous enum>)'

Is this code valid C++0x?

Comment: @Naveen: It's invalid C++03 that's supposed to be rejected, are you compiling in an 0x or non-standard mode?

Comment: AFAIK it should work; there's even a similar example in the template argument section. (Does the value being `sizeof ...` affect it?) @Naveen: It's invalid in C++03, local types cannot be template parameters.

Comment: @Roger Pate: VS2008 doesn't have 0x extensions. I am using the default compiler settings, not sure whether it is microsoft specific extension.

Comment: @Naveen: Actually, [the VC++ 9.0 compiler (used in VS2008) implements a few C++0x features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx). One of the C++0x features implemented in VC++ 9.0 was the ability to have local and unnamed types as template arguments. That's why the OP's code worked in VS2008, even though it's not valid C++03.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're doing this? Why aren't you just doing `size_t a_size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::fill is parameterized on the type of its object argument; it does not require an argument of Iterator::value_type. So, as In silico says, C++03 can't instantiate the template with a local type.

However, in C++0x, you can use local types to instantiate templates, because they are given external linkage.